# Tableview increasing memory?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have created a custom tableview. Other than that I also have some simple tableview. When I go to next custom table view from previous table view then memory increase. below is code for custom tableview. Please check.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ComponentCell";

    ClientAssessmentComponentCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {

        cell = [[ClientAssessmentComponentCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    SubComponent *componentInfo = [self.componentsData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.component_name.text = componentInfo.componentName;
    NSLog(@"status %d --- %@ ---- %@ ---- %@",(int)componentInfo.componentStatus,componentInfo.componentAllImages,componentInfo.componentNotes,componentInfo.componentScore);
    cell.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.dirty_btn.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.camera_img.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.count_img.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.count_lbl.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.notes_img.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.count_lbl.hidden = true;
    cell.count_img.hidden = true;
    cell.count_lbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.count_lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    cell.count_lbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    cell.a_btn.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.b_btn.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.c_btn.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.d_btn.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.e_btn.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.f_btn.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.dirty_btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(138/256.0) green:(138/256.0) blue:(138/256.0) alpha:1]];
    [cell.a_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.b_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.c_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.d_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.e_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.f_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *notes_tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(notesView:)];
    notes_tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [cell.notes_img addGestureRecognizer:notes_tap];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *image_tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(takePhoto:)];
    notes_tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [cell.camera_img addGestureRecognizer:image_tap];

    [cell.dirty_btn addTarget:self action:@selector(do_later_button_click1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.a_btn addTarget:self action:@selector(a_button_click1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.b_btn addTarget:self action:@selector(b_button_click1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.c_btn addTarget:self action:@selector(c_button_click1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.d_btn addTarget:self action:@selector(d_button_click1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.e_btn addTarget:self action:@selector(e_button_click1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.f_btn addTarget:self action:@selector(f_button_click1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        cell.component_name.font = [cell.component_name.font fontWithSize:22.0];
        cell.dirty_btn.titleLabel.font = [cell.dirty_btn.titleLabel.font fontWithSize:18.0];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.component_name.font = [cell.component_name.font fontWithSize:18.0];
        cell.dirty_btn.titleLabel.font = [cell.dirty_btn.titleLabel.font fontWithSize:14.0];
    }
    if(componentInfo.componentNotes != nil && componentInfo.componentNotes != NULL && ![componentInfo.componentNotes isEqual:@"(null)"] && ![componentInfo.componentNotes isEqual:@"null"])
    {
        cell.notes_img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"notes-with-glow.png"];
    }
    if(componentInfo.componentAllImages != nil && componentInfo.componentAllImages != NULL && ![componentInfo.componentAllImages isEqual:@"(null)"] && ![componentInfo.componentAllImages isEqual:@"null"] && ![componentInfo.componentAllImages isEqual:@""] )
    {
        cell.camera_img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"camera-with-glow.png"];
        NSArray *image_arr = [componentInfo.componentAllImages componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
        cell.count_img.hidden = NO;
        cell.count_lbl.hidden = NO;
        cell.count_lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)[image_arr count]];
        for(int x = 0; x < [image_arr count]; x++){
            NSString *imageName =[image_arr objectAtIndex:x];
            if([imageName containsString:@"http:"])
            {
                NSArray *imgNameSplit = [imageName componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
                NSLog(@"count is %lu",(long)[imgNameSplit count]);
                imageName = [imgNameSplit objectAtIndex:[imgNameSplit count]-1];
            }
            if(x == 0){
                self.componentImage.componentAllImages = imageName;
                self.componentImage.imageName =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                [self.componentImage.imageName addObject:imageName];
                self.componentImage.imageClickedTime = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                NSString *image_clicked_time = [self getClickTime];
                [self.componentImage.imageClickedTime addObject:image_clicked_time];
                self.componentImage.componentAllImagesTime = image_clicked_time;
            }
            else{
                self.componentImage.componentAllImages = [self.componentImage.componentAllImages stringByAppendingString:@", " ];
                self.componentImage.componentAllImages = [self.componentImage.componentAllImages stringByAppendingString:imageName];
                [self.componentImage.imageName addObject:imageName];
                NSString *image_clicked_time = [self getClickTime];
                [self.componentImage.imageClickedTime addObject:image_clicked_time];
                self.componentImage.componentAllImagesTime = [self.componentImage.componentAllImagesTime stringByAppendingString:@", "];
                self.componentImage.componentAllImagesTime = [self.componentImage.componentAllImagesTime stringByAppendingString:image_clicked_time];
            }
        }
    }
    if(componentInfo.componentStatus == 1)
    {
        [cell.dirty_btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(138/256.0) green:(138/256.0) blue:(138/256.0) alpha:1]];
    }
    else if(componentInfo.componentStatus == 2)
    {
        [cell.dirty_btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(138/256.0) green:(138/256.0) blue:(138/256.0) alpha:1]];
    }
    else if(componentInfo.componentStatus == 3)
    {
        [cell.dirty_btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(252/255.0) green:(78/255.0) blue:(59/255.0) alpha:1]];
    }
    else if(componentInfo.componentStatus == 4)
    {
        [cell.dirty_btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(138/256.0) green:(138/256.0) blue:(138/256.0) alpha:1]];
    }
    if([componentInfo.componentScore intValue] == 1)
    {
        [cell.a_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_checked.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.b_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.c_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.d_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.e_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.f_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else if([componentInfo.componentScore intValue] == 2)
    {
        [cell.b_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_checked.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.a_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.c_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.d_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.e_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.f_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else if([componentInfo.componentScore intValue] == 3)
    {
        [cell.c_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_checked.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.b_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.a_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.d_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.e_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.f_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else if([componentInfo.componentScore intValue] == 4)
    {
        [cell.d_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_checked.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.b_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.c_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.a_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.e_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.f_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else if([componentInfo.componentScore intValue] == 5)
    {
        [cell.e_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_checked.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.b_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.c_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.d_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.a_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.f_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else if([componentInfo.componentScore intValue] == 6)
    {
        [cell.f_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_checked.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.b_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.c_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.d_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.e_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.a_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Please help me out. How can I resolve memory issue for this case?

Comment: what is warning exactly?

Comment: It propably has something to do with all the images you allocate. Everytime a cell is shown it allocates all of your images, maybe try to do it differently. Less images perhaps?

Comment: I guess plus with memory issue, your table is also has lags while scrolling with this all `if`s and `for` cycles. Very painful code. Indeed it needs so much optimizations.

Comment: Try to optimize your code by using blocks for selectors and pre defining values from `- (void)awakeFromNib {
 // Initialization code}` method. Your conditions are troubling you.

Comment: can you post some sample code for me

Comment: I doubt that this is the "shortest possible code" to demonstrate the problem. It's also completely unclear if the problem is within this code or not. Use Instruments to track the missing memory (and what objects you are leaking). Build a minimal example and show it here.

Comment: i used instrument to see leaks but i don't see such leaks but memory is keep on increasing when i switch between table views

Answer (score 0):

You should register this cell at ViewDidLoad first, then try put those common setting in Cell's `(void)awakeFromNib` method.